# replacing nested for loops to make faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have three nested loops that compute the distance of each point in one group to all other points in the same group.  we can calculate these distances before and save them in a matrix, but the problem is that during the program the members of each group can change. executing these loops is very time-consuming. I want to know is it a way to do these loops in a matrix way or a way faster? I would be appreciated it if you have any suggestions for replacing these `for` loops.

```
 for itr2 in range(K):
                    tmp_cl=clusters[itr2+1]
                    if len(tmp_cl)>1:
                        BD_cent=np.zeros((len(tmp_cl),1))
                        for itr3 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                            sumv=0
                            for itr5 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                                value=BD_RATE('VMAF_Y',rate,tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate,tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                                if value!=np.NINF:
                                    sumv+=np.abs(value)
                                else:
                                    sumv+=1000#for curve which have not overlap with others
                            BD_cent[itr3]=sumv/len(tmp_cl)
                        
                        new_centroid_index=np.argmin(BD_cent)
                        centroid[itr2]=clusters[itr2+1][new_centroid_index]
```

Comment: use vectorisation in numpy so you don't need to do the iteration "in Python".  this should give you a chance of making things ~100times faster.  if you need more than this you'll need to give more details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you apre probably even good with the numpy internal methods. Especially have a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Comment: @SamMason, how can I do this with vectorization? I am not familiar with this. could please explain more?

Comment: @user_na, could you please explain more? how these two above links could help me?

Comment: @david I'd recommend searching for things like "numpy vectorisation" and "numpy broadcasting".  for example, the following post has an example with a similar set of nested loops https://heinzermch.github.io/posts/on-vectorization-and-broadcasting/